# How do i find collection through a record related to the first collection

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

I need to find a group of collection WHERE the search is based on a record on a related model.
To let you understand I need to get users with the company name that is LIKE my search input.

Here's what i've tried:

```
$users = App\User::with(['company' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('company_name', 'like', '%'.$searchInput.'%');
}])->paginate(10);
```

To be honest I spent hours on this but with no luck. I'm using `jenseggers/mongodb` on laravel 5.8.

Comment: Have you tried `whereHas`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Yes i did with no luck

Comment: Please post the relevant relationship definitions too.

Comment: Also because i cant pass any variable as the query

Comment: Companies hasMany users and users belongsTo Company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `::whereHas()` to your query which will limit query results where `company` is like the search query.

Also you will need to change the `::with()` closure to `::with('companies')`.

```
$users = App\User::whereHas('company', function ($query) use ($searchInput) {
    $query->where('company_name', 'like', '%'.$searchInput.'%');
})
->with('company')
->paginate(10);
```

Note the `use ($searchInput)`.

Also check if the user relation is `companies` instead of `company`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i was looking for. No mention in the docs about the use. whereHas was my first try but i got the error becuase of the missing var.

Comment: Welcome @McMazalf. Yes very good to know about `use`, please mark as correct.

Comment: Anyway no need to change company to companies. Thanks again!